# Grails cxf plugin - customize cxf endpoint display page

Tags: grails, cxf

i would like to customize the view of the published Endpoint Page, that is generated by the cxf-plugin (`http://localhost:8080/myApp/services`). The display of the SOAP Endpoints should have the layout of the entire app as well as access is restricted by by spring security. My question is, how this is possible to accomplish?

My first idea would be to customize the output of this Servlet via CSS, but i'm struggling how to get this done. The problem here is, that authorization information seem to be a problem.

Another alternative would be to create my own controller and display the information in a customized fashion. The problem is here, that i'm not aware of the possibilities to get on the information about the endpoints, the WSDL documents and so on, that are published via the /services Servlet.

The third, but worst solution (at least from my perspective) could be to create my own controller, do a http get on /services, parse the html and extract the endpoint information via approach.

Perhaps anyone has done this already before and can give me a hint how to get the endpoint information into my controller.

Thanks for your help!

Comment: The Cxf plugin has a Github repo so it is possible to learn about the internals. It seems that it creates a child Spring app context which can be used to query the endpoints.

Comment: thx, although i'm not sure, how the /services page is generated (perhaps anywhere in CFXServlet) there is another way to get this done: the plugin registers a new artefact type: "endpoints", which can be acessed via application.endpointClasses

Comment: I think the /services page is generated by a servlet because I did not see a controller and a GSP view for the URL.